# How can I edit my code to echo the data of child's element where my search term was found in, in XMLReader?

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I am new in XMLReader, and I think is kind of hard to find tutorials/code or something advanced to get examples.
My question is how can I transform the code I have now, so if I search (through a form) the term jQuery will give me the opportunity to output the value of `<info></info>` (and later other elements) in every `<name></name>` that is found in ?

**This is the code that output the names of the books.**

```
<?php
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open("books.xml");
while ($reader->read()) {
   switch ($reader->nodeType) {
   case (XMLREADER::ELEMENT):

                  if ($reader->localName == "name") {
                     $reader->read();
                     echo $reader->value;
                     break;
                  }}}
?>
```

**the xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<library>
    <book isbn="781">
        <name>SCJP 1.5</name>
        <info>Sun Certified Java Programmer book</info>
    </book>
    <book isbn="194">
        <name>jQuery is Awesome!</name>
        <info>jQuery Reference Book</info>
    </book> 
    <book isbn="199">
        <name>jQuery 101</name>
        <info>All you need to know about jQuery</info>
    </book> 
</library>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're bound to XMLReader for sequential parsing then you can build some parser based on it.

One method to simplify the parsing operation is to encapsulate it into an iterator, especially if you're working on a sequence. For example with an iterator named `XMLBookIterator` you could just `foreach` over all books *while* the data is being parsed:

```
$books = new XMLBookIterator($file);

foreach($books as $key => $book)
{
    echo 'book (', $key, '):', "\n";
    print_r($book);
}
```

A result could look like this with your example data:

```
book (0):
stdClass Object
(
    [isbn] => 781
    [name] => SCJP 1.5
    [info] => Sun Certified Java Programmer book
)
book (1):
stdClass Object
(
    [isbn] => 194
    [name] => jQuery is Awesome!
    [info] => jQuery Reference Book
)
book (2):
stdClass Object
(
    [isbn] => 199
    [name] => jQuery 101
    [info] => All you need to know about jQuery
)
```

Then it's only left to filter the books based on your term. This can be implemented into a `FilterIterator`, let's call it `BookFilterIterator`:

```
$filtered = new BookFilterIterator($books, 'jQuery');

foreach($filtered as $key => $book)
{
    echo 'book (', $key, '):', "\n";
    print_r($book);
}
```

The output would then be reduced to only the matching books:

```
book (1):
stdClass Object
(
    [isbn] => 194
    [name] => jQuery is Awesome!
    [info] => jQuery Reference Book
)
book (2):
stdClass Object
(
    [isbn] => 199
    [name] => jQuery 101
    [info] => All you need to know about jQuery
)
```

The only thing left is the actual code that does this. It's a bit longer, in it's heart - the `next()` function inside the iterator you will find a state-based parser that is reading over the XML like you already started with in your question. The difference is, that it has some sort of state which helps to fill up the current book entry which is stored as a private member of the class.

[Code](https://gist.github.com/1097266), [Demo](http://codepad.org/7RerAOvB)

The demo code uses you XML as string which is then converted into a pseudo "file" via `$file = 'data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($xml);`. The iterator works with any filename, it just get's passed to `XMLReader` anyway, so for large data, use a file.

Comment: Hi hakre your answer will help me a lot. I am on a phone device now and I will check it soon and reply. One quick question though, building parsers and iterators will have improvement on speed and performance? I guess it is a yes but I am waiting for your explanation. Thank you again!

Comment: Your code (as obvious) works great and it is what I want, so I am accepting it. Please tell me (or modify your code) how can I load an external xml file instead of having it in the script ? And finally how can I echo the `info` of the filtered book?

Comment: Just pass the filename to the iterator instead of the demo "file" I created. And for the info, each `$book` is an object, you can access info like so: `$book->info`. See the `print_r` output as well and my comment below "Code, Demo". That's referring to the file loading. The iterator will accept any file XMLReader does accept as well.

Comment: Hakre, the script grabs the data needed to perform an operation and skip to the next iteration, right ?

Comment: yes, it goes one after one, it advances on the data and consumes the part it needs to read the next book. It's made as an iterator. That's why the filtering works so well additionally on top. No need to keep all books in memory.

Comment: I read that XMLReader/SAX are faster than simplexml. I have tried your code to find the same things, and the difference was huge, with simplexml to be a lot of faster. Do you know why is that ?

Comment: @sampas: This can depends on multiple things. For the iterator `->next()` routine there is room for speed-optimizations. Next to that even if iterators are quite fast in PHP, non-capsulated and un-rolled code most often is faster. Keep in mind that this implementation is written with PHP, whereas simplexml is C code. But the speed comparison will most likely change when the XML grows. Depends on multiple things, so ideally you can have multiple methods which work the same so you can change the strategy when needed.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation hakre, You helped me a lot and cleared my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) -- it's better:

```
<?php
$books  = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');
$search = 'jquery';
foreach ($books->book as $book) {
    if (preg_match('/' . preg_quote($search) . '/i', $book->name)) {
        echo $book->name . ' (' . $book->info . ')<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I have to go with XMLReader. The reason is because my file is big and will grow bigger day by day. I wished that there was a way to handle it with SimpleXML though.