# Preg_replace expression for replace anchor tag

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have the following string:

```
<table width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href='/model/SMGCLX-6200FX/_/_/Samsung/CLX-6200FX/' title='Samsung CLX-6200FX Fuser-ela Unit-lv'>CLX-6200FX</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='/model/SMGCLX-6210FX/_/_/Samsung/CLX-6210FX/' title='Samsung CLX-6210FX Fuser-ela Unit-lv'>CLX-6210FX</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='/model/SMGCLP-610ND/_/_/Samsung/CLP-610ND/' title='Samsung CLP-610ND Fuser-ela Unit-lv'>CLP-610ND</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to remove all anchor tags like `<a href='/model/SMGCLX-6200FX/_/_/Samsung/CLX-6200FX/' title='Samsung CLX-6200FX Fuser-ela Unit-lv'>` and

How can I do this with `preg_replace`?

I tried using wild card `.*` but it's not working.

Comment: `DOMDocument` should help

Comment: and what output you expected with this input?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778209/how-to-remove-link-with-preg-replace

Comment: Only simple table structure with its <td> value

Comment: try  - `preg_match("~<a .*?</a>~", $html, $data);
echo strip_tags($data[0]),"\n";`

Comment: try `preg_replace('/<\/?a[^>]*>/','',$Source);`

Comment: Thank you all. I get simple soultion `strip_tags($string, '<table><tr><td>');`  which keeps only table structure and remove all other tags.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I get simple soultion

```
$output = strip_tags($string, '<table><tr><td>');
```

which keeps only table structure and remove all other tags

Answer (score 0):

This would work for the a tags only

```
$testStr = <<< "EOF"
    <table width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href='/model/SMGCLX-6200FX/_/_/Samsung/CLX-6200FX/' title='Samsung CLX-6200FX Fuser-ela Unit-lv'>CLX-6200FX</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='/model/SMGCLX-6210FX/_/_/Samsung/CLX-6210FX/' title='Samsung CLX-6210FX Fuser-ela Unit-lv'>CLX-6210FX</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='/model/SMGCLP-610ND/_/_/Samsung/CLP-610ND/' title='Samsung CLP-610ND Fuser-ela Unit-lv'>CLP-610ND</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
EOF;

preg_replace('(\</?a[^\>]*\>)', '', $testStr);
```