# Is there any faster/better way instead of using preg_match in the following code?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I edit my code to echo the data of child's element where my search term was found in, in XMLReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775785/how-can-i-edit-my-code-to-echo-the-data-of-childs-element-where-my-search-term)

this code finds if there is the string 2004 in `<date_iso></date_iso>` and if it is so, I echo some data from that specific element that the search string was found.

I was wondering if this is the best/fastest approach because my main concern is speed and the XML file is huge. Thank you for your ideas.

this is a sample of the XML

```
<entry ID="4406">
    <id>4406</id>
    <title>Book Look Back at 2002</title>
    <link>http://www.sebastian-bergmann.de/blog/archives/33_Book_Look_Back_at_2002.html</link>
    <description></description>
    <content_encoded></content_encoded>
    <dc_date>20.1.2003, 07:11</dc_date>
    <date_iso>2003-01-20T07:11</date_iso>
    <blog_link/>
    <blog_title/>
</entry>
```

this is the code

```
<?php
$books  = simplexml_load_file('planet.xml');
$search = '2004';
foreach ($books->entry as $entry) {
    if (preg_match('/' . preg_quote($search) . '/i', $entry->date_iso)) {
        echo $entry->dc_date;
    }
}
?>
```

this is another approach

```
<?php
$books  = simplexml_load_file('planet.xml');
$search = '2004';
$regex = '/' . preg_quote($search) . '/i';
foreach ($books->entry as $entry) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $entry->date_iso)) {
        echo $entry->dc_date;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main concern is speed, you shouldn't use simplexml or any other DOM-based xml parsing for this; use a SAX-based parser. Furthermore, don't use preg_match if you only want to do simple substring matching (use strpos).

If speed isn't really your concern but being idiomatic is, use an XPath 2.0 implementation (don't know if there is one for PHP) or do other XPath-based regex matching things - a quick google shows exslt options, or simpler xpath 1.0-based string matching options.

Comment: I have made some tests with SAX, XMLReader and SimpleXML. The test was to echo all the dc_date that 2004 was found in date_iso. I must say that SAX/XMLReader was way too slower than simplexml... This is the source code I tried madwe by hakre http://codepad.org/7RerAOvB

Comment: XMLReader is still way too high-level for a simple situation like this - what with the visitor, iterator etc abstractions. Take a look at XML Parser - just set up a handler for entry, dc_date and date_iso elements to make a simple state machine, use strpos to test for substring matching, and you're good to go. An approach like this won't even have to read the whole file into memory - XMLReader does, as far as I can tell and remember. I guess when I said 'SAX-based' I should have qualified that as 'event-based SAX parser'.

Comment: So to clear my mind, you suggest me to use XML Parser instead of XMLReader for speed and memory performance, right ?

Comment: Right. I've used it in the past for parsing huge files that I didn't want to load into memory all at once. It's much more low level than SimpleXML or any of the other API's are, but that's what makes it fast.

Comment: Great I guess this is what I am looking for then. I will find examples/tutorials and try to code it. I may be back to you for some questions

Comment: Roel, is this the correct class to use or is it a different thing ? http://www.criticaldevelopment.net/xml/doc.php Can you provide me a start point?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php .

Comment: I used this example http://www.codehelp.co.uk/php/xmlparse1.php in a 160mb file but I got a Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted. Isn't supposed that it should not load the whole document in memory ?

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` is a regular expression function, if you only need to do simple string comparisons, most often it's recommended to not use regular expression for it.

An alternative to your use of `preg_match` would be to compare the beginning of the `<date-iso>` contents against the year:

```
if ($search === substr($entry->date_iso, 0, 4))
```

as the date is always in the same format (hopefully) and starts with the year. You could also add the `-` to the search string and then compare against the first 5 characters.

Comment: How does your example change, if instead of date_iso that has 4 characters to use the title of the book that does not have a fix number of chars?

Comment: you can test that with `strpos` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php