# PHP XML Parser xml_set_default_handler splits special character

Tags: php, xml-parsing

The XML parser of PHP calls the default handler function twice when it encounters a special character in a string and therefore splits the string. I've tried to solve it using different encodings on the XML header as well in the PHP code, but it still splits the string:

```php
$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);

xml_set_element_handler($parser, "startTag", "endTag");
xml_set_default_handler($parser, 'defaultHandler');


function startTag($p, $name, $attributes)
{

}

function endTag($p, $name)
{

}

function defaultHandler($parser, $data)
{
    if(strlen(trim($data)) > 0)
        echo '[' . $data . ']' . '<br />';
}
```

Example of the XML:

```xml
<variable name="GZH29" type="integer">
    <label>This is a small test with a special ë character. Let's try an ë character too</label>
</variable>
```

One would expect:

```
[This is a small test with a special ë character. Let's try an ë character too]
```

But the result is

```
[This is a small test with a special ]
[ë character. Let's try an ë character too]
```

I would like not to have the line splitted, so any idea what the solution is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xml_parser` does create multiple events here for a reason I didn't finally understood fully, I think this is because of the encoding auto-detection.

You can deal with that by creating your own parser class. This is generally useful anyway, not only in this case. But for this case it's especially so that you can put together the text of the label which get's distributed over multiple events.

The basic work is making the callback functions public function of a class, and register these functions then.

Then each time the `label` tag opens, a temporary store is reset. When text appears, it's added to that temporary store. If the `label` tag then closes, you can pass this text to a new "event" this time the function you're looking for with it's text:

```
$variableParser = new VariableParser($parser);

$file = 'data://,'.$xml;
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
while(!feof($fp)) { $data = fread($fp, 4096); xml_parse($parser, $data, feof($fp)); }


class VariableParser
{
    private $label = ''; # place for the label text
    public function doLabel($text)
    {
        printf("[%s]<br />\n", $text);
    }
    public function __construct($parser = NULL)
    {
        if ($parser) $this->register($parser);
    }
    public function register($parser)
    {
        xml_set_element_handler($parser, array($this, "startTag"), array($this, "endTag"));
        xml_set_default_handler($parser, array($this, 'defaultHandler'));
    }

    public function startTag($parser, $name, $attributes)
    {
        if ($name === 'label') $this->label = '';
    }

    function endTag($parser, $name)
    {
        if ($name === 'label')
        {
            $this->doLabel($this->label);
            $this->label = '';
        }
    }

    function defaultHandler($parser, $data)
    {
        if(strlen(trim($data)) > 0)
        {
            $this->label .= $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to extract each `label` tag of the XML into a string and insert it into a database. I also tried it with `xml_set_character_data_handler` but it gives the same result. It's a large XML file containing 1000's of these `variable` and `label` tags.

Comment: A probably option: Set the target encoding to UTF-8 - it has all characters and needs no entities - and after you got the text as UTF-8  re-encode it to ISO-8859-1, probably with transliteration as you won't be able to insert every character of the text into the database as Latin-1. Sounds practical?

Comment: I've tried several encodings for target and source. Changed the XML encoding to UTF but it still didn't work. It's strange that it breaks only on the first special character.

Wasn't aware of the XMLReader class in PHP, changed code to use that class it this give no problems.

Comment: In which encoding is your original XML file/string? The XML Reader is fine, I have compiled some example code for step-by-step reading with it in some [(different) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6777403/367456) (just for reference, you can ignore that for a moment). - If you tell the original encoding would be good to know to compile an example. Also if you could add the code where you "load" that file in your question, would be more concrete as well to give better suggestions.

Comment: The XML is in ISO-8859-1 encoding and it's an export from an application, so I've got no control on that one. The code I'm using is 
`while(!feof($fp))
    {
        $data = fread($fp, 4096);
        xml_parse($parser, $data, feof($fp));
    }`

Comment: I thought of that answer too, concatenate the string but then I encountered the XmlReader class in PHP and that one works like a charm. So I've rewritten the class to use that one instead of the xml parser. It's also a bit faster.

Comment: Okay, well I linked the XMLReader above ;) While compiling the example code I first wanted to use it as well but I thought you need xml_parser. That's how life plays ;)